# Java extended enum for switch statement

Tags: java, android, enums, switch-statement

I have the following code

```
public interface EnumInterface{
   public String getTitle();
}


public enum Enum1 extends EnumInterface{
  private String title;
  Enum1(String title){
    this.title = title;
  }

  A("Apple"),B("Ball");
  @Override
  public String getTitle(){
    return title;
  }
}

public enum Enum2 extends EnumInterface{
  private String title;
  Enum1(String title){
    this.title = title;
  }

  C("Cat"),D("Doll");
  @Override
  public String getTitle(){
    return title;
  }
}
```

and I am using it in other class as follows

```
private EnumInterface[] enumList;//declared globally.

if(flagTrue){
  enumList = Enum1.values();
}else{
  enumList = Enum2.values();
}
....
....
private method1(int position){
  switch(enumList[postion]){
    case A:....
           break;
    case B:....
           break;
    case C:....
           break;
    case D:....
           break;
  }
}
```

I am getting the following compilation time error

> Cannot switch on a value of type EnumInterface. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted.

I did my research and found that if I do it this way, the 'switch' case is not possible.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Can you please demo a piece of code for the same. Thank you

Comment: @Raj what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @blackbelt I have created Enums to create list of elements. as you can see the EnumList is dynamically decided. According to the item selected in the list I want to call a method.

Comment: so if A is selected  you want return Apple?

Comment: No if A is selected I call a method which will internally use the method getTtile() with other logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Switch Statement is absolutely not what you want in this case. Even if the above example worked, and it does not for a reason, your results would be completely wrong. The switch on an enum is using the enum ordinal, which is 0 for `Enum1.A`, 1 for `Enum1.B`, 0 for `Enum2.C`, and 1 for `Enum2.D` using your classes above. You can see why this would be a really bad idea.

Your `EnumInterface` class is not tied of the Java type `enum` in any way, it just defines any class that implements it and provides your `getTitle()` method. This could be `Enum1`, `Enum2`, or any other class that might not even be an Enum. So when you want to switch based on the `EnumInterface`, you need to ask yourself what you actually want to switch on. Is it the title you want to be using as your conditional, or do the enums you defined bring something else to the table?

Now, I'm going to give you the benefit of the doubt and assume that whatever you are trying to do, it needs to be keyed off of an Enum.  I will also assume that you cannot combine `Enum1` or `Enum2` for whatever reason. Below is my completely over-engineered solution for you:

```
public interface EnumInterface {

    public String getTitle();

    public void processEvent(SwitchLogicClass e);
}


public enum Enum1 implements EnumInterface{

    A("Apple"){
        public void processEvent(SwitchLogicClass e){
            //Any A specific Logic
            e.doSomethingA();
        }
    },
    B("Ball"){
        public void processEvent(SwitchLogicClass e){
            //Any B specific Logic
            e.doSomethingB();
        }
    };

    private String title;
    Enum1(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }


    @Override
    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }
}
```

Repeat for Enum2.  Assume that the next class is called SwitchLogicClass

```
private EnumInterface[] enumList;//declared globally.

if(flagTrue){
    enumList = Enum1.values();
}else{
    enumList = Enum2.values();
}
....
....
private method1(int position){
    EnumInterface[position].processEvent(this);
}


public void doSomethingA(){
    //Whatever you needed to switch on A for
}

public void doSomethingB(){
    //Whatever you needed to switch on B for
}

....
....
```

You will almost certainly need to refactor based on whatever abstraction patterns you need to use, but the above is the best I can do with what I know of your code.

Answer (score 0):

What did the extending accomplish that can't be done using a simple java `enum` ?
You can just use `if else` blocks and and invoke `equals` method.

Comment: I am create a List of elements using Enums. On an Item clicked in the list I want to call a method. The list will be decided dynamically depending on the flow of app